# Why does GNU find suppress printing -prune'd directories when another "-or" test is applied?

Tags: find

I have a directory with the following files and a `.git` directory, e.g.

```
.
├── .git
│   ├── branches
│   ├── COMMIT_EDITMSG
│   ├── packed-refs
│   └── refs
├── readme.md
├── server_build.sh
└── tags
```

If I run GNU `find` command with the `-prune` test, `find` prints the directory which is `prune`'d:

```
% find . -name '.git' -prune
./.git
```

If add another OR option, then the directory which is pruned not longer appears in the output:

```
% find . -name '.git' -prune -o -name '*.md' -print
./readme.md
```

In this case, both `-name '.git'` and `-name '*.md'` tests must be returning true, it can't be possible that adding another OR test suddenly makes the `-name '.git' -prune` test untrue.
Is there some implicit switch being added to the first statement?
In other words is find turning

```
find . -name '.git' -prune
```

into

```
find . -name '.git' -prune -print
```

at run time? and the implicit `-print` is taken away  when the next test when is added?
Why doesn't `find` print the -prune'd directory when another "-or" test is applied?

Comment: try `find . \( -name '.git' -prune -o -name '*.md' \) -print` also there is some discussion on this in `man find` just before `EXIT STATUS`

Comment: `find . -name '.git' -prune` prints `.git` because there is no other action.  On the other hand, `find . -name '.git' -prune -o -name '*.md' -print` is actually equivalent to `find . \( -name '.git' -prune \) -o \( -name '*.md' \) -a -print `, and `-prune` no longer prints anything since there _is_ another action.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I thought `-prune` was an action, and therefore the implicit `-print` would not be used here.

Comment: From the manual: _If the expression contains no actions __other than -prune__, -print is performed on all files for which the expression is true._

Comment: @SatoKatsura I think thats actually the answer

Comment: `-prune` is not a test, it's an action.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '.git' -prune
```

is the same as

```
find . -name '.git' -prune -print
```

so it prunes and then prints

```
find . -name '.git' -prune -o -name '*.md' -print
```

is the same as

```
find . \( -name '.git' -prune -true \) -o \( -name '*.md' -print \)
```

so it does first clause, if it does prune then it does true (prune returns true), and does not do right hand side of `-o`

These will always print

```
find . \( -name '.git' -prune -o -name '*.md' \) -print
find . -name '.git' -prune -print -o -name '*.md' -print
```

Comment: ah I think I understand. So its possible to perform TWO actions on matching files. so ` find . -name '.git' -prune -print` is the same as ` find . -name '.git' -a -prune -a -print` .? and `-print` would not  happen if prune returned false?

Comment: @the_velour_fog yes.

Comment: thanks, although in your answer where you say `find . -name '.git' -prune -o -name '*.md' -print` is the same as `find . \( -name '.git' -prune -true \) -o \( -name '*.md' -print \)` and *and does not do right hand side of `-o`*. the right hand does get run - its the only statement that produces output. i.e.  output is: `./readme.md`

Comment: Yes rhs should get evaluated when not `-name '.git'`.